# При клике на любое место, возникает ошибка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Пр клике в любой области документа, в консоле возникает вот эта ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую зануленный шаблон с themeforest. Нашел в каком файле происходит ошибка, но не знаю где именно. Код файла

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
/* ==========================================================================
 Scroll
 ========================================================================== */

 if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {

  document.documentElement.className += " no-touch";

  var jScrollOptions = {
   autoReinitialise: true,
   autoReinitialiseDelay: 100
  };

  $('.scrollable .box-typical-body').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions);
  $('.side-menu').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions);
  $('.side-menu-addl').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions);
  $('.scrollable-block').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions);
 }

/* ==========================================================================
    Header search
    ========================================================================== */

 $('.site-header .site-header-search').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this),
   overlay = parent.find('.overlay');

  overlay.click(function(){
   parent.removeClass('closed');
  });

  parent.clickoutside(function(){
   if (!parent.hasClass('closed')) {
    parent.addClass('closed');
   }
  });
 });

/* ==========================================================================
    Header mobile menu
    ========================================================================== */

 // Dropdowns
 $('.site-header-collapsed .dropdown').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this),
   btn = parent.find('.dropdown-toggle');

  btn.click(function(){
   if (parent.hasClass('mobile-opened')) {
    parent.removeClass('mobile-opened');
   } else {
    parent.addClass('mobile-opened');
   }
  });
 });

 $('.dropdown-more').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this),
   more = parent.find('.dropdown-more-caption'),
   classOpen = 'opened';

  more.click(function(){
   if (parent.hasClass(classOpen)) {
    parent.removeClass(classOpen);
   } else {
    parent.addClass(classOpen);
   }
  });
 });

 // Left mobile menu
 $('.hamburger').click(function(){
  if ($('body').hasClass('menu-left-opened')) {
   $(this).removeClass('is-active');
   $('body').removeClass('menu-left-opened');
   $('html').css('overflow','auto');
  } else {
   $(this).addClass('is-active');
   $('body').addClass('menu-left-opened');
   $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
  }
 });

 $('.mobile-menu-left-overlay').click(function(){
  $('.hamburger').removeClass('is-active');
  $('body').removeClass('menu-left-opened');
  $('html').css('overflow','auto');
 });

 // Right mobile menu
 $('.site-header .burger-right').click(function(){
  if ($('body').hasClass('menu-right-opened')) {
   $('body').removeClass('menu-right-opened');
   $('html').css('overflow','auto');
  } else {
   $('.hamburger').removeClass('is-active');
   $('body').removeClass('menu-left-opened');
   $('body').addClass('menu-right-opened');
   $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
  }
 });

 $('.mobile-menu-right-overlay').click(function(){
  $('body').removeClass('menu-right-opened');
  $('html').css('overflow','auto');
 });

/* ==========================================================================
    Header help
    ========================================================================== */

 $('.help-dropdown').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this),
   btn = parent.find('>button'),
   popup = parent.find('.help-dropdown-popup'),
   jscroll
  ;

  btn.click(function(){
   if (parent.hasClass('opened')) {
    parent.removeClass('opened');
    jscroll.destroy();
   } else {
    parent.addClass('opened');

    if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
     setTimeout(function(){
      jscroll = parent.find('.jscroll').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions).data().jsp;
     },0);
    }
   }
  });

  $('html').click(function(event) {
      if (
          !$(event.target).closest('.help-dropdown-popup').length
          &&
          !$(event.target).closest('.help-dropdown>button').length
          &&
          !$(event.target).is('.help-dropdown-popup')
          &&
          !$(event.target).is('.help-dropdown>button')
      ) {
    if (parent.hasClass('opened')) {
     parent.removeClass('opened');
     jscroll.destroy();
          }
      }
  });
 });

/* ==========================================================================
    Side menu list
    ========================================================================== */

 $('.side-menu-list li.with-sub').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this),
   clickLink = parent.find('>span'),
   subMenu = parent.find('>ul');

  clickLink.click(function() {
   if (parent.hasClass('opened')) {
    parent.removeClass('opened');
    subMenu.slideUp();
    subMenu.find('.opened').removeClass('opened');
   } else {
    if (clickLink.parents('.with-sub').size() == 1) {
     $('.side-menu-list .opened').removeClass('opened').find('ul').slideUp();
    }
    parent.addClass('opened');
    subMenu.slideDown();
   }
  });
 });


/* ==========================================================================
    Dashboard
    ========================================================================== */

 $(window).resize(function(){
  $('body').click('click');
 });

 // Collapse box
 $('.box-typical-dashboard').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this),
   btnCollapse = parent.find('.action-btn-collapse');

  btnCollapse.click(function(){
   if (parent.hasClass('box-typical-collapsed')) {
    parent.removeClass('box-typical-collapsed');
   } else {
    parent.addClass('box-typical-collapsed');
   }
  });
 });

 // Full screen box
 $('.box-typical-dashboard').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this),
   btnExpand = parent.find('.action-btn-expand'),
   classExpand = 'box-typical-full-screen';

  btnExpand.click(function(){
   if (parent.hasClass(classExpand)) {
    parent.removeClass(classExpand);
    $('html').css('overflow','auto');
   } else {
    parent.addClass(classExpand);
    $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
   }
  });
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 Select
 ========================================================================== */

 if ($('.bootstrap-select').size()) {
  // Bootstrap-select
  $('.bootstrap-select').selectpicker({
   style: '',
   width: '100%',
   size: 8
  });
 }

 if ($('.select2').size()) {
  // Select2
  //$.fn.select2.defaults.set("minimumResultsForSearch", "Infinity");

  $('.select2').not('.manual').select2();

  $(".select2-icon").not('.manual').select2({
   templateSelection: select2Icons,
   templateResult: select2Icons
  });

  $(".select2-arrow").not('.manual').select2({
   theme: "arrow"
  });

  $('.select2-no-search-arrow').select2({
   minimumResultsForSearch: "Infinity",
   theme: "arrow"
  });

  $('.select2-no-search-default').select2({
   minimumResultsForSearch: "Infinity"
  });

  $(".select2-white").not('.manual').select2({
   theme: "white"
  });

  $(".select2-photo").not('.manual').select2({
   templateSelection: select2Photos,
   templateResult: select2Photos
  });
 }

 function select2Icons (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
   '<span class="font-icon ' + state.element.getAttribute('data-icon') + '"></span><span>' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
 }

 function select2Photos (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
  var $state = $(
   '<span class="user-item"><img src="' + state.element.getAttribute('data-photo') + '"/>' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
 }

/* ==========================================================================
 Tooltips
 ========================================================================== */

 // Tooltip
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  html: true
 });

 // Popovers
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  trigger: 'focus'
 });
 
/* ==========================================================================
 Full height box
 ========================================================================== */

 function boxFullHeight() {
  var sectionHeader = $('.section-header');
  var sectionHeaderHeight = 0;

  if (sectionHeader.size()) {
   sectionHeaderHeight = parseInt(sectionHeader.height()) + parseInt(sectionHeader.css('padding-bottom'));
  }

  $('.box-typical-full-height').css('min-height',
   $(window).height() -
   parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-top')) -
   parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-bottom')) -
   sectionHeaderHeight -
   parseInt($('.box-typical-full-height').css('margin-bottom')) - 2
  );
  $('.box-typical-full-height>.tbl, .box-typical-full-height>.box-typical-center').height(parseInt($('.box-typical-full-height').css('min-height')));
 }

 boxFullHeight();

 $(window).resize(function(){
  boxFullHeight();
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 Chat
 ========================================================================== */

 function chatHeights() {
  $('.chat-dialog-area').height(
   $(window).height() -
   parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-top')) -
   parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-bottom')) -
   parseInt($('.chat-container').css('margin-bottom')) - 2 -
   $('.chat-area-header').outerHeight() -
   $('.chat-area-bottom').outerHeight()
  );
  $('.chat-list-in')
   .height(
    $(window).height() -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-top')) -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-bottom')) -
    parseInt($('.chat-container').css('margin-bottom')) - 2 -
    $('.chat-area-header').outerHeight()
   )
   .css('min-height', parseInt($('.chat-dialog-area').css('min-height')) + $('.chat-area-bottom').outerHeight());
 }

 chatHeights();

 $(window).resize(function(){
  chatHeights();
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 Box typical full height with header
 ========================================================================== */

 function boxWithHeaderFullHeight() {
  /*$('.box-typical-full-height-with-header').each(function(){
   var box = $(this),
    boxHeader = box.find('.box-typical-header'),
    boxBody = box.find('.box-typical-body');

   boxBody.height(
    $(window).height() -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-top')) -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-bottom')) -
    parseInt(box.css('margin-bottom')) - 2 -
    boxHeader.outerHeight()
   );
  });*/
 }

 boxWithHeaderFullHeight();

 $(window).resize(function() {
  boxWithHeaderFullHeight();
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 File manager
 ========================================================================== */

 function fileManagerHeight() {
  $('.files-manager').each(function(){
   var box = $(this),
    boxColLeft = box.find('.files-manager-side'),
    boxSubHeader = box.find('.files-manager-header'),
    boxCont = box.find('.files-manager-content-in'),
    boxColRight = box.find('.files-manager-aside');

   var paddings = parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-top')) +
       parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-bottom')) +
       parseInt(box.css('margin-bottom')) + 2;

   boxColLeft.height('auto');
   boxCont.height('auto');
   boxColRight.height('auto');

   if ( boxColLeft.height() <= ($(window).height() - paddings) ) {
    boxColLeft.height(
     $(window).height() - paddings
    );
   }

   if ( boxColRight.height() <= ($(window).height() - paddings - boxSubHeader.outerHeight()) ) {
    boxColRight.height(
     $(window).height() -
     paddings -
     boxSubHeader.outerHeight()
    );
   }

   boxCont.height(
    boxColRight.height()
   );
  });
 }

 fileManagerHeight();

 $(window).resize(function(){
  fileManagerHeight();
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 Mail
 ========================================================================== */

 function mailBoxHeight() {
  $('.mail-box').each(function(){
   var box = $(this),
    boxHeader = box.find('.mail-box-header'),
    boxColLeft = box.find('.mail-box-list'),
    boxSubHeader = box.find('.mail-box-work-area-header'),
    boxColRight = box.find('.mail-box-work-area-cont');

   boxColLeft.height(
    $(window).height() -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-top')) -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-bottom')) -
    parseInt(box.css('margin-bottom')) - 2 -
    boxHeader.outerHeight()
   );

   boxColRight.height(
    $(window).height() -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-top')) -
    parseInt($('.page-content').css('padding-bottom')) -
    parseInt(box.css('margin-bottom')) - 2 -
    boxHeader.outerHeight() -
    boxSubHeader.outerHeight()
   );
  });
 }

 mailBoxHeight();

 $(window).resize(function(){
  mailBoxHeight();
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 Nestable
 ========================================================================== */

 $('.dd-handle').hover(function(){
  $(this).prev('button').addClass('hover');
  $(this).prev('button').prev('button').addClass('hover');
 }, function(){
  $(this).prev('button').removeClass('hover');
  $(this).prev('button').prev('button').removeClass('hover');
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 Addl side menu
 ========================================================================== */

 setTimeout(function(){
  if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
   $('.side-menu-addl').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions);
  }
 },1000);


/* ==========================================================================
 Header notifications
 ========================================================================== */

 // Tabs hack
 $('.dropdown-menu-messages a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');

  // Scroll
  if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
   jspMessNotif = $('.dropdown-notification.messages .tab-pane.active').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions).data().jsp;
  }
 });

 // Scroll
 var jspMessNotif,
  jspNotif;

 $('.dropdown-notification.messages').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
   jspMessNotif = $('.dropdown-notification.messages .tab-pane.active').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions).data().jsp;
  }
 });

 $('.dropdown-notification.messages').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
   jspMessNotif.destroy();
  }
 });

 $('.dropdown-notification.notif').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
   jspNotif = $('.dropdown-notification.notif .dropdown-menu-notif-list').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions).data().jsp;
  }
 });

 $('.dropdown-notification.notif').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
   jspNotif.destroy();
  }
 });

/* ==========================================================================
 Steps progress
 ========================================================================== */

 function stepsProgresMarkup() {
  $('.steps-icon-progress').each(function(){
   var parent = $(this),
    cont = parent.find('ul'),
    padding = 0,
    padLeft = (parent.find('li:first-child').width() - parent.find('li:first-child .caption').width())/2,
    padRight = (parent.find('li:last-child').width() - parent.find('li:last-child .caption').width())/2;

   padding = padLeft;

   if (padLeft > padRight) padding = padRight;

   cont.css({
    marginLeft: -padding,
    marginRight: -padding
   });
  });
 }

 stepsProgresMarkup();

 $(window).resize(function(){
  stepsProgresMarkup();
 });

/* ========================================================================== */

 $('.control-panel-toggle').on('click', function() {
  var self = $(this);
  
  if (self.hasClass('open')) {
   self.removeClass('open');
   $('.control-panel').removeClass('open');
  } else {
   self.addClass('open');
   $('.control-panel').addClass('open');
  }
 });

 $('.control-item-header .icon-toggle, .control-item-header .text').on('click', function() {
  var content = $(this).closest('li').find('.control-item-content');

  if (content.hasClass('open')) {
   content.removeClass('open');
  } else {
   $('.control-item-content.open').removeClass('open');
   content.addClass('open');
  }
 });

 $.browser = {};
 $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
 $.browser.msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
 $.browser.mozilla = /firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

 if ($.browser.chrome) {
  $('body').addClass('chrome-browser');
 } else if ($.browser.msie) {
  $('body').addClass('msie-browser');
 } else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
  $('body').addClass('mozilla-browser');
 }

 $('#show-hide-sidebar-toggle').on('click', function() {
  if (!$('body').hasClass('sidebar-hidden')) {
   $('body').addClass('sidebar-hidden');
  } else {
   $('body').removeClass('sidebar-hidden');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: проблемный код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy Он слишком длинный

Comment: значи надо убрать все лишнее и сделать [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy Дело в том, что я не знаю где именно там возникает ошибка.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Вставил код в сообщение

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jScrollPane is not a function_

Comment: слишком много зависимостей)

Comment: ну так я и говорю - выкидывай все лишнее, оставляй минимальный пример, запустив который, можно получить ту же ошибку, что и сейчас

Comment: Вопросы вида "Есть задача, решите её" тут... не приветствуются, по очевидным причинам. Гугление по ошибке подсказало что эта ошибка выскакивает тогда, когда функция, которую живкери отслеживает, отсутствует. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32231036/6275986

Comment: Я  сюда обратился уже от безъисходности) хотя это ошибка не влияет на работоспособность, она каждый раз вылазиет в консоли, и это не приятно) вопрос по ссылке я видел, не помогло)

Comment: слишком большая шторка